# Dynamic Cron Job in Node with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, cron

I need to create a service in NodeJS that periodically executes a GET request to an API that return all the Jobs/Tasks. The service then needs to create a CronJob for each task returned while continuing to check for new tasks, and if there are new ones create new CronJobs.
I made something similar by having a service that runs a GET and then does a forEach loop and creates new CronJobs. But this doesn't take in account new tasks that are created after the first initialization. How do I solve this? How do I make a service that is always looking for new tasks and dynamically creates them?
EDIT1: the axios.post just post a log on a database, nothing special

```
const axios = require("axios");
const CronJob = require("cron").CronJob;
const cron = require("cron");

const startCron = async () => {
  const schedules = await axios
    .get("http://127.0.0.1:4000/")
    .then((res) => {
      return res.data;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

  schedules.forEach((schedule) => {
    return new CronJob(`${schedule.timing} * * * * *`, () => {
      let d = new Date();
      console.log(schedule.message + " in data: " + d);
      axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:4000/${schedule.id}`);
    }).start();
  });
};

startCron();
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Where are you planning to host this application? PAAS's such as Google Cloud provide functionality to run Cron jobs easily, but you need to provide more info about the architecture and code samples.

Comment: If you have to implements cron task in node.js, you have many package on npmjs that do the job - node-cron for example.

Comment: I have added a code example of what i have made so far, I don't actually know where this will be hosted sorry